# How to save datagridview records on database table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datagridview

In my application, I show database table in a datagridview. Now I want to modify and change some records and save this changes on database. How can I do this?

Comment: How do you get and bind your data to GridView?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one example with BindingSource:

```
      string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.bimar";
      da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
      SqlCommandBuilder cBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
      dt = new DataTable();

      da.Fill(dt);

      BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
      bSource.DataSource = dt;

      dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
```

when you change your data in dataGridView1 , update it:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        da.Update(dt);
    }
```

Comment: This is the way to go. The benefit to using a datatable as your datasource is that you can modify the dataview of that datatable to enable filtering like so:
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "field = 'value'";

Answer (score 2):

[TableAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx.aspx)s are one way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 objDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
        objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = objConnection;
        objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select code,name,family,fatherName,age from bimar";
        objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        objConnection.Open();
        objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet, "bimar");
        objConnection.Close();
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = objDataSet;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "bimar";
```

i use this code to show my table on DataGridView , i want to after doing some work on DatagridView  the data gets inserted back to db